# Show 3 Activity in One Screen

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity, android-framelayout

I have 3 FrameLayout in my program.

I have three FrameLayout in my program. I want in the each one, one Activity will be displayed.
Is there such a thing possible?
Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

you can't have multiple Activities on screen at once(interacting with user). see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5476354/android-viewing-two-activities-in-one-screen) post.but  maybe you can use [AndroidFragments](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/fragments.html) and [ActivityGroup](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityGroup.html)